# Pandas Reading json gives me ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type in Ploty Dash

Tags: json, pandas, plotly-dash

This line:

```
        else:
            #add to this
            nutrients_totals_df = pd.read_json(total_nutrients_json, orient='split')
```

is throwing the error.
I write my json like:

```
nutrients_json = nutrients_df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')
```

Then I stash it in a hidden div or `dcc.Storage` in one callback and get it in another callback.  How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read json files that i've written with Pandas, I use the function below and call inside of json.loads().

```
def read_json_file_from_local(fullpath):
    """read json file from local"""
    with open(fullpath, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    return data

df = json.loads(read_json_file_from_local(fullpath))
```